# How to test an integration to mercadopago using test users?

Tags: java, integration-testing

In order to test a MercadoPago integration the [documentation](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-users/) tells that you need at least two test users: a seller and a buyer. It also explains how to create them but not how to use them.
I suppose the seller info should be hard-coded somewhere in the server side. Where? Is there a field in the preference data to specify the seller user?

I know there is a `payer` field and I used it to specify the buyer. But what about the seller?

I already tried filling the `client_id` and `collector_id` fields of the preference data with the test-user id with no avail.

```
MP mp = new MP("???", "????");
JSONObject preference = mp.createPreference("{items:[...], client_id: 262046207}");
```

Where `262046207` is the test-user id of one of the two test users I generated. 
When the user submits a payment he gets this error message: "Una de las partes es un usuario de prueba."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create two test users: one for acting as the buyer, and the other for acting as the seller. [Here are the instructions](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-users/) to create a test user.
2. Log out if you are already logged in.
3. [Log in to MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar) with the seller test user using the e-mail and password you obtained in step 1. If the login dialog asks for your password before the e-mail, click the link "*no soy ...*" which is below the login dialog.
4. Then go to [this link](https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/account/credentials?type=basic) to obtain the credential you need to authenticate programmatically from the server.
5. Then go to [this link](https://www.mercadopago.com/mlm/herramientas/notificaciones) to configure the URL where your server will listen to the MercadoPago notifications. If you have a router, don't forget to open the port.
6. At the time of testing a purchase, log in to MercadoPago with the e-mail and password of the buyer test user.
7. To pay with credit cards, use any of [these cards numbers](http://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-payments/). The other fields can be filled with anything, but the card holder's name should start with any of the prefixes enumerated at the bottom of the mentioned page.